# Is there any error checking web app cralwers out there?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

Wondering if there was some sort of crawler we could use to test and re-test everything when changes are made to the web app so we know some new change didn't error out any existing pages. Or maybe a web browser with a million frames so I could scroll down and look through the tiles to find any error pages... you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium will let you test forms and write and automate scripts. This is a firefox add in and is quite powerful. You can manually write the scripts and also "record" them

Jmeter will let you create scripts and then run them as multiple users to test and load test web sites as a whole. This a stand alone application and can mimic multiple users and randomise access etc. and loading to stress test the application.

You could presumably use both to error test by monitoring the output logs from them to catch errors.
Both will allow you to authenticate to log on to sites.